# Error when installing biopython package

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-7, biopython

I get the following error when I installed biopython 1.63 package :

```
building 'Bio.cpairwise2' 
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

I am working with Win 7, installed Python 3.3

Comment: Can you please follow this link and let us know what's the update: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat

Comment: I will install visual studio then I tell you

Comment: I tried all the answers but no thing change, I get the same error:Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

Comment: are you sure that biopython 1.63 is supported in Python 3.3? Please check that first.

Comment: yes.biopython1.63 required python 3.3

Comment: I just tried myself! I believe your OS is 64 bit. If your Python 3.3 (I mean Python 3.3.0) is already installed, try this link to install the biopython package for 64 bit: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#biopython

Hopefully, will solve your problem!